# HHVM breaks on NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, hhvm

Laravel throws `Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException` and then `App::missing()` catches this, atleast it does that in non HHVM PHP but how would i catch the exception in HHVM?

Answer (score 4):

HHVM aims to execute any PHP so you would catch it the same way with `try {} catch {}`.

Comment: Got that, Laravel 4.0 throws the exception and tries to handle it afterwards. Updated to 4.1 which had an updated Router.php that solved this.